# UI freezes when I add random numbers to a listbox on a separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, loops, invoke

When I load the windows form, **using a new thread**, I add a random number to a listbox every second and when it reaches 10 numbers, I generate a new set of 10 random numbers. However, at the moment, I am having a problem with the UI thread. The random numbers are being added to the listbox, but I have no control over the form. When I try to interact with the form, UI freezes. Am I using the MethodInvoker incorrectly. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread ranThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RandomList));
        ranThread.IsBackground = true;
        ranThread.Start();         
    }

public void RandomList()
    {
        stack = new Stack<int>(); 
        while (loop)
        {
            if (lbxStackRndNum.InvokeRequired)
            {
                lbxStackRndNum.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        Random rnd = new Random();

                        if (lbxStackRndNum.Items.Count == 10)
                        {
                            stack.Clear();
                            lbxStackRndNum.Items.Clear();
                        }

                        int rndVal = rnd.Next(1, 10000);
                        stack.Push(rndVal);
                        lbxStackRndNum.Items.Insert(0, rndVal);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are calling `Thread.Sleep(1000)` inside the invoked delegate, which means it will make the UI thread to sleep and not `ranThread`.

```
public void RandomList()
{
    stack = new Stack<int>(); 
    while (loop)
    {
        if (lbxStackRndNum.InvokeRequired)
        {
            lbxStackRndNum.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();

                    if (lbxStackRndNum.Items.Count == 10)
                    {
                        stack.Clear();
                        lbxStackRndNum.Items.Clear();
                    }

                    int rndVal = rnd.Next(1, 10000);
                    stack.Push(rndVal);
                    lbxStackRndNum.Items.Insert(0, rndVal);
                }));
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the actual work is done in the main UI thread via Invoke() and the delegate, and all the thread is really doing is acting as a one second timer via Sleep()...why don't you just add a regular Timer() from the ToolBox to your form, set the Interval to 1000, and place your code in the Tick() event?

Comment: Normally, I'd do that, but I'm learning about Threading, Unsafe Code and ActiveX and I want to incorporate as much as possible into the program for the learning benefits. Thanks though